# Who are Ashta Dikpalakas? what is their job?

Tags: belief, practice, demi-god

What are the duties & responsibilities of Ashta Dikpalakas? Are they considered gods/demigods? Can they be worshiped for any specific purpose?

Why are Ūrdhvā & Adho dikpalakas are not prominent?

I heard eating, reading, worshiping/sadhana, travelling in each of these directions will bestow something! Is it true? If yes, please explain.

Comment: Dik- means direction; paalaka means ruler. Therefore, dikpalaka means the person who is the ruler of that direction/disha/dik. We know that there are eight direction of a plane surface. Also thare are two directions vertically that is above/oordhwa/zenith/aakash and below/adho/nadir/paatal.The vertical directions are not taken into consideration in Vaasthu shastra.

Comment: If daily recited the slokams of Ashta Dikbalagas we will be guarded by them. In Tamil book Kudumba jodidam slokas are given which contain 4 lines for each balagas.

Answer (score 2):

***Ashta Dikpalakas (Dikpalas) :***

*Ashta Dikpalas* are the guardians of direction. There are eight deities who are responsible for protecting the eight directions of the world, they are known as Ashta Dikpalakas. They are:

> Kubera : for North (Uttara)
>   Yama     : for South (Dakshina)
>   Indra    : for East (Pūrva)
>   Varuna : for West (Paścima)
>   Isana (Shiva) : for North-East (Īśānya)
>   Agni : South-East (Āgneya)
>   Vayu : North-West (Vāyavya)
>   Nirrti (sometimes Raksasa) : South-West (Nairṛti)

In addition to these there are two more deities added for extra dicrections and then the Dikpalakas are considered as being 10 or  ***Dasa-Dikpalakas***, being

> Brahma : Zenith (Ūrdhva)
>   Vishnu : Nadir (Adho)

The *Ūrdhva* and *Adho* are also considered, but not so prominent, because the major use of the Dikpalakas as enlisted in the *Vastu-Shastra* which observes only the eight major directions.

The *Vastu-Shahstra* on relation with the eight direction, defines the eating,sleeping, reading and worshiping habbits, a common e.g. is not to sleep with your legs facing the *South(Dakshina)* direction.

The ***Dikpalas*** are also considered as ***Lokpalas*** when considered as the guardian of universe directions.

- [Ashta Dikpalakas](http://www.vastusai.com/ashta-dikpalakas.html)
- [Asta Dikpalas](http://hinduonline.co/HinduReligion/Gods/AstaDikpalas.html)
- [Guardians of the directions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_directions)

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I will add links :)

Comment: @Mr.K Then who is the ruler of these dikpalakas?

Comment: @JavaTechnical, the guardians are the only rulers, technically they don't behave like a ruler but helpers or guardians, but as they guard them, they rule them.

Comment: Could someone explain , what exactly they guard directions from ?. What is the need to have guardians for directions ? I am bit curious, do they guard directions to stop rakshasas or danavas coming to earth?.

Comment: its complex thing to explain, don't u think directions can also change there positions if the earth rotates and revolves and there are so many complex anatomies going on ... the guarding is like keeping them consistent not constant, secondly they guard direction of closed place like house or temple from negative energies.